# Averaging several cross-correlations

Tags: time-series, correlation, mean, cross-correlation

I tried searching and see questions about averaging correlation coefficients, but my question relates to averaging cross correlations.

I have more than 10 thousand time-series records that relate to 420 different companies. For each company I have a timestamp (month/year) and a number of variables (around 10). Time-series are not of the same length among different companies, but are of the same length for each individual company.

Question: I want to calculate "average" cross-correlation for my variables for the whole sample. I can calculate cross-correlation between two variables for each company, but how can I average the results across all companies?

With "pure" correlations, I can calculate correlation coefficient between two variables for each individual company and then average it using Fishers' transformation. But what to do with cross-correlations?